# Let a function return different types depending on the values of the arguments

Tags: haskell

Given this interface:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies   #-}
module Tlf where

import           Data.Dynamic  (Dynamic, fromDyn, toDyn)
import           Data.Kind     (Type)
import           Data.Proxy    (Proxy (Proxy))
import           Data.Typeable (Typeable)

data Q = Q1 | Q2
       deriving (Show)

data R1 = R1 deriving (Show)
data R2 = R2 deriving (Show)

newtype TL (a :: [Type]) = TL { unTL :: Dynamic }

someFun :: Q -> TL '[R1, R2]
someFun Q1 = (TL . toDyn) R1
someFun Q2 = (TL . toDyn) R2
```

I want to write a function that runs `someFunc` and extracts back the return value. This works:

```hs
myQ :: (Typeable a) => Proxy a -> Q -> a
myQ _ q = (fromDyn . unTL . someFun) q (error "This shouldn't happen!")
```

```
> myQ (Proxy :: Proxy R1) Q1
R1
```

But the additional `Proxy` is redundant and it is not as safe as it could be

```
*Tlf> myQ (Proxy :: Proxy R2) Q1
*** Exception: This shouldn't happen!
```

The thing is that I *know* that `Q1` will yield `R1`. So I wrote this:

```hs
type family FunRes (a :: Q) :: Type where
  FunRes 'Q1 = R1
  FunRes 'Q2 = R2
```

But now I am stuck on how to put the pieces together. I tried:

```hs
myQ' :: forall q. q -> FunRes q
myQ' q = (fromDyn . unTL . someFun) q (error "This shouldn't happen!")
```

But ghc says no:

```
    • Expected kind ‘Q’, but ‘q’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘FunRes’, namely ‘q’
      In the type signature: myQ' :: forall q. q -> FunRes q
```

I also tried a few other things, but I always stumble over the error given above.

Comment: Maybe you need a `singleton` GADT. It looks like you want to pass a value of type `Q` but you also want the type variable `q` to agree with that value. Singletons are a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to make `myQ` return different types depending on the values of arguments (*edit: when I wrote that, the question had a different title*). This cannot happen. Haskell just doesn't support this sort of thing.

(if you want to look it up and research more, this is called "dependent types" - because the types *depend* on the values)

In Haskell, you can do certain half-measures. For example, a popular approach is called "singleton", where you make yourself a GADT of cases tagged with values of `Q` promoted to types:

```
data SQ (q :: Q) where
  SQ1 :: SQ Q1
  SQ2 :: SQ Q2
```

And then you make a function to convert from `SQ` to `Q`:

```
reflectQ :: SQ q -> Q
reflectQ SQ1 = Q1
reflectQ SQ2 = Q2
```

And then `myQ` can become:

```
myQ :: Typeable (FunRes q) => SQ q -> FunRes q
myQ q = (fromDyn . unTL . someFun) (reflectQ q) (error "This shouldn't happen!")
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
> myQ SQ1
R1

> myQ SQ2
R2
```

---

But this has one obvious gotcha: you can only pass `SQ1` and `SQ2` at compile time. They can't come from, say, user input.

Or, to be more precise, they *can*, but then you're back to not knowing the type of result. It will have to remain generic. Like I said at the top, Haskell ultimately doesn't support dependent types.

---

Also, if you squint hard enough, you can see that `R1` and `R2` already kind of play the role of `SQ1` and `SQ2`, so you might as well just do this:

```
class RtoQ r where reflectRtoQ :: Q
instance RtoQ R1 where reflectRtoQ = Q1
instance RtoQ R2 where reflectRtoQ = Q2

myQ :: forall a. (Typeable a, RtoQ a) => a
myQ = (fromDyn . unTL . someFun) (reflectRtoQ @a) (error "This shouldn't happen!")

> myQ @R1
R1

> myQ @R2
R2
```

This is *slightly* worse than the "singleton" approach, because the values of `SQ` can be passed around, stored in data structures, and all the other things you can do with values, whereas types `R1` and `R2` cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer and sorry for simply quoting your answer as question title, but I was very unhappy with the previous question titles and your first sentence seemed to sum it up pretty well.

Comment: Sure thing, glad I could help